# Enhanced for loop starting part way through List

Tags: java, list, for-loop

Im a beginner in Java and I had this doubt. Is it possible to use the Enhanced for loop in Java on an ArrayList, but start at the specified point rather than ArrayList[0].

```
For eg. ArrayList<Integer> calc = new ArrayList<Integer>;
       // calc contains {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

Can I use enhanced for loop and start iterating from calc[2] rather than calc[0]?? If possible, how can I do that?
In my particular case, using a enhanced for loop would be better, rather than a normal for loop.

Comment: When I need the index, whatever are the reasons, I never use enhanced for loops. The enhanced for is exactly the same as foreach in c#: it loops every object contained within a list and process them.

Comment: Why do you think that enhanced for loop would be better?

Comment: @duffymo I basically want to iterate over the ArrayList...And Enhanced for loop is the best for that purpose...but I want to start at a different point rather than ArrayList[0]...so I wondered if enhanced for loop can be modified to suit my purpose?

Comment: No need for "basically".  I know what you want.  I'm disagreeing with your insistence that the enhanced loop is "best".  No, it can't be modified.  Use the traditional for loop and be done with it.

Comment: BTW It is recommended to use collection interface instead of actual implementation where possible, so instead of ArrayList<Integer> calc = new ArrayList<>(); I would suggest to use List<Integer> calc = new ArrayList<>(); That way switching from one implementation of list to another is a matter of a one place change (and time to think of consequences, esp. time complexity).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best way in Java would be like this:

```
for (Integer i : calc.subList(start, calc.size()) {
  ... 
}
```

`subList` is an efficient *view* of the original list, so it's almost exactly what you need.

### UPDATE

OK, motivated by Mikera's comments, I benchmarked it on `jmh`. This is the benchmarked code:

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.GenerateMicroBenchmark;

public class Benchmark1
{
  static final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList(asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));
  static { for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) list.addAll(list); }

  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  public long testIterator() {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i : list) sum += i;
    return sum;
  }
  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  public long testIndexed() {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) sum += list.get(i);
    return sum;
  }
  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  public long testSublistIterator() {
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i : list.subList(1, list.size())) sum += i;
    return sum;
  }
  @GenerateMicroBenchmark
  public long testIndexedSublist() {
    long sum = 0;
    final List<Integer> l = list.subList(1, list.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) sum += l.get(i);
    return sum;
  }
}
```

And these are the results:

```
Benchmark        ops/msec
-------------------------
Indexed          1860.982
IndexedSublist   1642.059
Iterator         1818.657
SublistIterator  1496.994
```

#### Conclusions:

1. *enhanced for* on the main list is as fast as indexed iteration, once past the initialization cost;
2. traversal of the sublist is *somewhat* slower than of the main list, and iteration is *somewhat* slower than indexed traversal;
3. all the differences are negligible for all practical purposes.

Comment: "best" depends on whether you care about conciseness or performance, I believe. subList adds a small amount of overhead vs. a traditional indexed loop.

Comment: No, "best" depends on what the question is about: using enhanced for. But, while on the performance page, indexed iteration is acceptable only if done on the static type of `ArrayList`; otherwise you're risking an O(n2) meltdown.

Comment: Well if you want to play at being pedantic, List.subList() could be even worse than O(n^2) - you have no guarantee how it is implemented :-) The question does specify ArrayList however, so we are both safe.

Comment: OK, no guarantee, but let's be realistic :) But never mind that, do you say that `x.subList().iterator()` is even worse than `x.iterator()`? Because it is obvious that this first step is already adding quite a bit of overhead, especially if we have many, many loops: it's *some* allocation idiom vs. *none at all*. So your point may not be specific to `subListe`, but primarily to *enhanced for*.

Comment: Now that you mentioned the spec, I'm reading it... this quote is interesting because it shows that `subList` is *specifically* meant to help in a use case just as ours: "This method eliminates the need for explicit range operations (of the sort that commonly exist for arrays). Any operation that expects a list can be used as a range operation by passing a subList view instead of a whole list." This implies even more strongly that any sane implementation will have this done cheaply.

Comment: Yes, I've checked the source (Java 6) for `ArrayList`. At least for this class, `subList().iterator()` adds almost no overhead at all: the implementation is virtually identical to the main `ArrayList.iterator()`.

Comment: Stop speculating and benchmark it already: I get indexed access running 2.5x faster than a sublist iterator (about 20ns vs. 50ns for a simple loop calculating the sum of the OP's example ArrayList).

Comment: Sure, indexed access is faster than iterator---and this is exactly as valid for `subList` as the main list! Benchmark indexed acces on the result of `subList`, you'll see no difference (my hypothesis, I'm currently between microbenchmark tools so can't run it ATM).3

Comment: Also, if you're testing OP's list, which is very short, you are not comparing iteration speed, but mainly the overhead of starting the loop.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I have a simple doubt..is it possible to access the next element in the sublist inside the loop when iterating using enhanced for loop?? if so, how do i do that?

Comment: @user2358330 No, with enhanced for you don't have any knowledge of where you are in the list. If you need such a thing, better switch to indexed iteration.

Comment: @mikera I've set up `jmh` and run the benchmarks. I have repeated your finding that iteration over `subList` is drammatically slower---as opposed to the iteration on the main list, which is virtually identical to indexed traversal.

Comment: @mikera Whoops... I messed up the key method, `testSublistIterator`. After correction the large gap is gone. It is only *somewhat* slower, negligible for any practical purpose. Good to know, it got me worried for a while...

Comment: @Marko: there's something odd with your benchmark results: 1800 ops/ms means over 500ns per execution? They should be in the 20-50ns range (I used Google's Caliper, which is generally better for very fine grained microbenchmarks like this). I suspect jmh overhead is drowning out the actual difference in performance (which I still get as 2.5x faster for indexed usage). Note you are also iterating over more elements in the indexed case :-)

Comment: @mikera Did you take into account that I'm iterating over 320 elements? 1.5 ns per element seems not bad at all to me. `jmh` is a serious tool, which certainly controls for its own overhead, or so I am lead to believe :) I switched over to it from Caliper on assylias' advice. Second thing: I don't see that I'm iterating over more elements in the indexed case, please give me a hint :)

Comment: Ah sorry, didn't spot your clever list-extending trick :-). That mostly explains it. You're starting the indexed loop at 0 vs. 1 for the non-sublist cases, but this doesn't make much difference for big lists. I get 1.5x faster for indexed access of size 320 lists vs sublists. So some of the fixed overhead seems to get amortised, but not all. I agree with your conclusions, apart from the fact that the difference isn't always negligible: It depends on the use case. I certainly have simulation applications where 1.5x differences in inner loops are important, i.e. noticeably affect total runtime.

Comment: @mikera I see what you mean with 0 vs. 1, but both sublist cases start at 1, and both main list cases start at 0 (here I refer to the absolute indexes in the main list). And of course, it's just 319 against 320. 1.5x is not negligible, but I have measured only 20% speed loss in the sublist iterator compared to main list indexing. And note that we're only comparing traversal *overhead*, which will only rarely dominate list traversal. So, in that one special case, where you do almost no work in an iteration step, and 20% is important, *enhanced for* + `subList` is a disadvantage.

Comment: @mikera BTW in performance-critical context the first thing I would recommend against is `List<Integer>`. Switching to `int[]` will give more like a 200% difference (could be much more!), especially on larger arrays, where the dense packing of `int`s makes a big difference to CPU caches.

Comment: +1 Nice one ;-) be careful with stuff that always returns the same result. It very often gets optimised away. I generally use a random generator and also use a baseline method that just does the random generation to have a comparison point.

Comment: @assylias Yes, in earlier benchmarks I was careful to initialize `sum` with `rnd.nextInt()`, but since here my results are consistent with the loops actually running all the way through, I didn't bother.

Answer (score 5):

You're stuck using a traditional loop here...

```
for (int i = 2; i < calc.size(); i++) {
    Integer x = calc.get(i);
}
```

Well, unless you're willing to create a temporary [subList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) just for using an enhanced for loop, which is fine, because sublists are views of the original list and don't create a new list object:

```
for (Integer x : calc.subList(2, calc.size())) {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for(Item e : list.subList(1, list.size())) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `list.size()` rather than `list.size() - 1` because the second argument of `subList()` `toIndex` is exclusive, not inclusive.

Comment: @Adam true. Updated, just in case. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through the [sublist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html), as below:

```
for (Integer integerMember : calc.subList(2, calc.size()) {
    // operation here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that the enhanced for loop is less efficient for `ArrayList` then standard indexing. This is because we have to create an `Iterator` object and call `hasNext` and `next` on it on each step of the loop, causing unnecessary overhead.

For this reason I would recommend indexing in the traditional way rather than using the `sublist` approach.